# USE Excel to transpose ONLY unique column into a header row

Tags: excel, dynamic, unique, formula, transpose

I am trying to transform a spreadsheet in SHEET1 that looks like this:

```
COLUMN1
A 
A 
A 
B 
B 
B 
B 
C
```

I want it to be in SHEET2 like this

```
ROW Header: A B C
```

I am basically trying to:

Get unique items in first column
Transpose and promote these items as column headers

I need the output table in SHEET 2 to dynamically update each time. No VBA. for example if I add D to SHEET 1, D will automatically update on SHEET 2 Header.... A B C D

```
COLUMN1
A 
A 
A 
B 
B 
B 
B 
C 
D
```

I want it to automatically update in SHEET2 like this

```
ROW Header: A B C D
```

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would a formula like this work for you? It takes all the values of the column in sheet 1 and transposes the unique values. Putting this formula in sheet 2 will automatically update a header as the values in sheet 1 change.

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A500,Sheet1!A2:A500<>"")))
```

EDIT: This formula will only work for those with Excel O365 and later since the newer versions allow for more dynamic formulas.

Comment: Brilliant!! thank you so much this formula saved me! :D

Comment: hi @Dgoodman333  I was wondering if you could help me with my query 
once the rows are in place I cant seem to get the formula on the second row to drag across without manually dragging     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735768/dynamic-excel-report-make-excel-formula-automatically-add-itself-when-new-rows?

Answer (score 2):

Try `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,3,ROW($A$5:$A1000)/((COUNTIF($A$1:A$1,$A$5:$A$1000)=0)*($A$5:$A$1000<>"")),1)),"")
```

If column (you wrote `row`) headers start from `A1` then first header you should enter manually in `A1`, then in `B1` enter formula and copy to the right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! :)

Comment: hi @basic I was wondering if you could help me with my query     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735768/dynamic-excel-report-make-excel-formula-automatically-add-itself-when-new-rows?

Comment: once the rows are in place I cant seem to get the formula on the second row to drag across without manually dragging